# Increasing entity framework connections and queries

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have performance issue with my dotnet core project with entity framework core and mysql connector.

I created dbcontext by following tutorial: http://insidemysql.com/howto-starting-with-mysql-ef-core-provider-and-connectornet-7-0-4/

```
    public class MhdContext : DbContext
    {
        public MhdContext(DbContextOptions<MhdContext> options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
    }

    public static class MhdContextFactory
    {
        public static MhdContext Create(string connectionString)
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MhdContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseMySQL(connectionString);

            //Ensure database creation
            var context = new MhdContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            var serviceProvider = context.GetInfrastructure<IServiceProvider>();
            var loggerFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
            loggerFactory.AddProvider(new MyLoggerProvider());

            return context;
        }
     }
```

in my controller I call this method:

```
    public async Task<Vehicle[]> GetAllVehicles()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Getting All vehicles");
        using (var dbContext = MhdContextFactory.Create(_dbConfig.ConnectionString))
        {
            var vehicles = await dbContext.Vehicles.AsNoTracking()
                .FromSql("SELECT * FROM Vehicles AS v group by v.VehicleId order by LastUpdate")
                .ToArrayAsync();
            return vehicles;
        }
    }
```

After the 1st request everything looks like working

After few requests there are duplicate sql commands and increasing
7th request log: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ezyowyubq1orsn/7thRequest.txt?dl=0

Could you help me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would not be creating a static factory to return Context.  A 'context' in Entity Framework(EF) is an opening to a database.  You could run into trouble where you are reusing the same connection for different queries.  In general static's are great for core business usage of things like Public Static Add(int x, int y){ Return x + y }.  But for things like Data Access I avoid them and favor instance based.  Maybe I am wrong and some more Senior EF expert will come in and explain it away.  But typically I always DISPOSE of my context by wrapping a transaction scope as such where everything is contained in there:

```
(var context = new EFContext()) // NOT BASED ON FROM A STATIC FACTORY
{
  //Do some DB operation
}
```

In my work experience at companies that professionally use EF.  If they tried to use an IOC to have a static or instance of EF shared it gets mucked up over time.  When you stick to just opening, making a connection, doing something, CLOSING IT WITH DISPOSING IT(which is auto handled by using a 'using { }' block) it behaves better.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this with adding to my startup.cs this:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<MhdContext>(
            options => options.UseMySQL(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("MysqlConnection")));
    }
```

so my db contexte looks like now like this:

```
    public MhdContext(DbContextOptions<MhdContext> options) : base(options {}
```

In my controller I get instance with depencency injection:

```
    var dbContext = _serviceProvider.GetService<MhdContext>();
    return dbContext.Vehicles;
```